# Is it possible to use the Mobilklippekort in Copenhagen as a group ticket?

Tags: public-transport, copenhagen

Is it possible (and advisable from a practical point of view) to use the Mobilklippekort as a group ticket to get around city centre in Copenhagen?

Comment: What do you mean by "group ticket"?

Comment: If I understood correctly, Mobilklippekort provides a ticket for 20 zones, e.g. 10 rides in two zones. What I meant is can they be used all at the same time with 10 people instead of 10 rides by the same person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, as described at page 15 of [this official document in Danish](https://dinoffentligetransport.dk/media/2605/vejledningdokument_01062017.pdf), linked from https://dinoffentligetransport.dk/hjaelp-til-billetter/rejseregler/faelles-rejseregler/

Comment: This is true for tickets bought online, per sms or via the app, the second sentence of your cited document basically only means: you cannot share a single 4-zone ticket among two people - correct?

Comment: @dodi: Yes, that how I read it: They have to buy two 2-zone tickets (but can do so on the same phone) rather than one 4-zone ticket.